# Trace and index manipulation

Tags: tensor-calculus, conventions, notation, trace

Imagine that I have a quantity $F_{ab}$ multiplying the stress tensor $T^{ab}$:

\begin{equation}
F_{ab} T^{ab}.
\end{equation}
There is also a metric, say $h_{ab}$. If I want to write the above equation in terms of the trace, $T^a_a = T^{ab}h_{ab}$ (I think this is the right definition). Then can I write
\begin{equation}
F_{ab} T^{ab} h_{ab}h^{ab} = F_{ab}T^c_c h^{ab}
\end{equation}
or is this not an allowed computation? Since the summation convention is implicit, I changed notation from $T^a_a \to T^c_c$.

Edit: so it seems like the problem is that the indices appears too many times. But then the question is if a trace could be introduced on the RHS.

Comment: Indices ought to appear two times *only*.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail on how you got to this calculation? While this might initially seem superfluous, knowing a bit more about the context might help us understand what you are trying to do and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write $F_{ab}T^{ab}$ only in terms of the trace $T^a_a$. A simple argument is that
$$F_{ab}T^{ab}=F_{00}T^{00}+F_{01}T^{01}+\ldots + F_{10}T^{10}+\ldots
+ F_{dd}T^{dd}$$
involves all the matrix elements $T_{ab}$. In the special case of a diagonal metric, the trace involves only the diagonal elements $T_{aa}$. Therefore, $F_{ab}T^{ab}$ cannot be expressed only in terms of the trace.

In your calculation, you cannot use more than twice the same index:
$$F_{ab}T^{ab}=F_{ab}T^{ab}=F_{ab}T^{a}_{\ \ c}h^{cb}$$

Comment: Is it possible to introduce the trace on the RHS?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Simply to find out the trace $T^{ab}h_{ab}$ works and gives a scalar (easy to visualize when the metric is diagonal).

To get the RHS, try $F_{ab}T^{ab}h_{bc}h^{cd}\delta_d^b$=$F_{ab}T^a_ch^{bc}$.

Now do not rewrite the dummy $a$ to $c$ since new $c$ will be different than the esisting one, it becomes $F_{c'b}T^{c'}_ch^{bc}$

(Considered only symmetric tensors)